# Script has two variables when done, but when I pipe to SELECT-object only first one returns data to console

Tags: powershell, select-object

I am trying to query multiple servers with WMI, but I don't always have access to the servers.

The code is below.  Alas, it returns "access is denied" to the console, but I can't seem to get rid of it.  Oh well.

However, I **am** trapping the servers that I can't connect to, so that I can tell someone else to look at them, or request access.

But when I run the code, it only returns the first list of servers; even if $failed_servers has values, nothing is returned.  If I tell both to pipe to ogv, then two windows pop up.

Why won't both "$variable|select" work? If I remove the select on $failed_servers, then it shows up, albeit just sitting immediately underneath the successful ones.  Which is okay-but-not-great.

```
$list = ("servera","serverb","serverc")
$failed_servers = @()
$final = foreach ($server_instance in $list)
{
$errors=@()
gwmi -query "select * from win32_service where name like '%SQLSERVER%'" -cn $server_instance -ErrorVariable +errors -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($errors.Count -gt 0) {$failed_servers += $server_instance
}
}

$final|select pscomputername, name, startmode, state |where {$_.pscomputername -ne $null}

$failed_servers |select @{N='Failed Servers'; E={$_}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're experiencing is **merely a *display* problem**:

- Both your [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) calls produce output objects with *`4` or fewer properties* whose types *do not have explicit formatting data associated with them* (as reported by [`Get-FormatData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-formatdata)).
- This causes PowerShell's for-display output [formatting system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/formatting-file-overview) to implicitly render them via the [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) cmdlet.
- The **display columns that `Format-Table` uses are *locked in* based on the properties of the *very first object*** that `Format-Table` receives.
- Therefore, **your *second* `Select-Object` call, whose output objects *share no properties* with the objects output by the first one, effectively produces *no visible output*** - however, the objects *are* sent to the success output stream and *are* available for *programmatic processing*.

A simple demonstration:

```sh
& {
  # This locks in Month and Year as the display columns of the output table.
  Get-Date   | Select-Object Month, Year
  # This command's output will effectively be invisible,
  # because the property set Name, Attributes does not overlap with
  # Month, Year
  Get-Item \ | Select-Object Name, Attributes
}
```

The output will look something like this - note how the second statement's output is effectively invisible (save for an extra blank line):

```
Month Year
----- ----
    9 2021
```

Note the problem can even affect a *single* statement that outputs objects of disparate types (whose types don't have associated formatting data); e.g.:
`(Get-Date | Select-Object Year), (Get-Item \ | Select-Object Name)`

---

**Workarounds:**

- Applying `| Format-List` to the command above makes all objects visible, though obviously changes the display format.
- *Intra-script* you could pipe each `Select-Object` pipeline to `Out-Host` to force instant, pipeline-specific formatting, but - given that the results are sent directly to the *host* rather than to the success output stream - this technique *precludes further programmatic processing*.

---

**Potential future improvements:**

[GitHub issue #7871](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7871) proposes at least issuing a *warning* if output objects effectively become invisible.