# Powershell how to use Get-command to display specific columns?

Tags: powershell

I need to use 'Get-Command" to display three specific columns of information. Name, CommandType, and Module. I am new to PowerShell and have been searching for hours to find an answer but have not been able to find any documentation that explains how to do this specifically.

Comment: Note: The post previously believed to be a duplicate, [How to get an object's property's value by property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406315/how-to-get-an-objects-propertys-value-by-property-name), solves a _different_ problem, namely how extract a _single property value_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to use 'Get-Command" to display three specific columns of information. Name, CommandType, and Module

Since your intent is **to *display* the columns of interest**, in *tabular* format, you can use [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table):

```sh
Get-Command | Format-Table -Property Name, CommandType, Module
```

For quick *interactive* use, you can shorten the command, by using *aliases* and *positional* parameter binding:

```sh
gcm | ft name, commandtype, module
```

However, note that `Format-*` cmdlets are only suited to *for-display* formatting, not for outputting *data* suitable for later *programmatic processing* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375) and the `Select-Object` solution below.

---

By contrast, **if you need to *construct new objects* that have only a subset of the properties of the input objects** (while possibly adding new properties / transforming or renaming existing ones via [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties)<sup>[1]</sup>), you can use the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) cmdlet:

```sh
Get-Command | Select-Object -Property Name, CommandType, Module
```

Note: If you print this command's output *to the console* (host), it will *result in the same display output as the `Format-Table` call above*, because PowerShell *implicitly* uses `Format-Table` formatting for objects that have *4 or fewer* (public) properties.<sup>[2]</sup>

However, for explicit control of display formatting - such as if you want 5-property objects to be shown in tabular format too - `Format-*` cmdlets must be used.

---

<sup>[1] You may also use calculated properties with `Format-Table`, among other cmdlets.</sup>

<sup>[2] 5 or more properties result in `Format-List` formatting; Generally, this implicit formatting applies only to .NET types that do *not* have *predefined formatting data* associated with them; if they do, that data controls the default view and other aspects - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69201252/45375).</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Try piping it to select object

`get-command|select-object -expandpoperty Name, CommandType, and Module`

Comment: without switch `-expandpoperty` and the word `and` this would be good